# 2 dialog box functions under one PS

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get two dialog boxes to work under the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)`, they should pop up whenever someone enters a certain value into the range. Below is the code I am using.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 289 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    With Target.Offset(0, 69)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"


    If Target.Column <> 290 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    With Target.Offset(0, 72)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can anyone help me see where I am going wrong?

Comment: First of all you are missing first `End With` statement (I added it in the edit). Could you please point the error you are getting?

Comment: What "2 dialog box functions" should mean?

Comment: @TomaszPaluch Please don't change original code in questions. Instead write answers. Otherwise it is not useful.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Acknowledged, I am never gonna do it again :)